# Compare two lists for same entries at same place

Tags: python, list

I am trying to compare two lists for the same element at the same index. The idea is to verify whether both lists contain same element at the same index. If yes, I want to count such occurrences. Here is my code:

```
 count = 0
 a = ['.ps2\n >|<4 *|*.ps2xml', '.c\n >|<2 *|*.wsc', '.h\n >|<2 *|*.wsh', '.c\n >|<2 *|*.chm', '.h\n >|<2 *|*.hta'  ]
 b = ['.ps2xml', '.chm', '.hta']

 for x in a:
  for y in b:
   if y==x[x.index(" *|*")+4:]:
    print "match"
    count += 1

 print count
```

This gives me a count of 3. What I expect is 1 because only first element of b matched with a's first element. The second element of both lists differ. The third elements are also different. The remaining elements in list a should not count as there is no such index in b.

Hope it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the matching pattern here?

Comment: how `a[0] == b[0]`?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: If I understand it correctly the op uses a "special" way to match by first finding a pattern (`" *|*"`) and looks whether it is followed by the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case, you should **not use nested loops** (since this means you will repeat the search over `b` for each line in `a`); **but use a `zip(..)`**:

```
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    if y==x[x.index(" *|*")+4:]:
        print "match"
        count += 1

print count
```

`zip` takes some iterators and generates tuples. In this case the *i*-th tuple is thus `(a[i],b[i])` so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using [min()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function(***to get a limit size of compared sequences***):

```
for i in range(min([len(a), len(b)])):
    if (a[i][a[i].index('*|*') + 3:] == b[i]):
        count += 1

print(count)
```

The output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

does the match have to be qualified as following `'*|*'` ?

if not then really simple is:

```
sum([1 for e, f in zip(a, b) if f in e])
```

or in later versions of python where iterator args are automatically unpacked:

```
sum(f in e for e, f in zip(a, b)) # relies on bools True, False = ints 1, 0
```

if the match is just the last bit you could split

```
'.ps2\n >|<4 *|*.ps2xml'.split(" *|*")
Out[13]: ['.ps2\n >|<4', '.ps2xml']

'.ps2\n >|<4 *|*.ps2xml'.split(" *|*")[1]
Out[14]: '.ps2xml'

sum([1 for e, f in zip(a, b) if f in e.split(" *|*")[1]])
```

and while `sum()` is more "intentional" `len()` could be used for a speed advantage since it doesn't have to iterate over the list